# Cassandra, optimizing the in clause

Tags: hash, cassandra, partitioning, murmurhash

I was thinking about a way of optimizing in-clause like id in (1,2,3,....)?

- Get a hold of Murmur3Partitioner hashing function
- group in-clause by values that result in the same hash like "id in (x1, x3, ...)" with x1 and x3 having the same hash.
- passing that query to driver, the driver should be able to go to the partition-owner node?

So, how do I get a hold of Cassandra's Murmur3Partitioner hashing function so that I can calculate the hash in my code?

Is this theory going to work with Cassandra?

Comment: What language you using? The driver has the functionality in it.

Answer (score 2):

Drivers already do this if using [token aware load balancing policy](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/load_balancing/#token-aware-policy). Worth noting its not likely you will have multiple ids with same token, although they may be the same coordinators.

In general its a bad idea to try to batch up requests like this. Unless you have an unusual scenario its better to just use executeAsync on each `id` and do a get on all of them. It will distribute and parallelize the coordination load across the cluster better and require less custom work. I highly recommend not prematurely optimizing and instead focus on having a correct data model. If you need to do work in batch use the spark loader/reader or look at it for a good example on doing it efficiently.